# How can I create a no-login account in OS X that will allow me to establish a reverse SSH tunnel?

Tags: macos, bash, ssh

I'd like to create a no-login account on my OS X (10.6.6) laptop at home so that I can establish a reverse SSH tunnel to it from my desktop at work.

My intention is to create cron job (at work) that periodically checks dropbox for a given file. If it is there, it will establish a reverse tunnel to my laptop at home. I will use SSH keys to eliminate the need to enter a password. However, I don't want just anyone to jump on to my machine and have shell access to my laptop.

Is creating a no-login account to work in this way possible? And, is it reasonable means of maintaining a high level of security?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the entry for the key in `~/.ssh/authorized_keys`, set the `no-pty` and/or `command` options so that no shell can be opened (`read` may be useful as the command). See the `sshd(8)` man page for details.

Comment: add no-pty option to ~/.ssh/authorized_keys is enforce on account level.  Is there an option to block pty from system level?